# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object - Linq on List

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

This error is being thrown when running a Linq query over a List.

I am using Unity3D 3.0 with C# (Unity3D uses Mono 2.6). Unity3D, as far as I know, is single-threaded. It works by attaching "scripts" (c# .cs files) that inherit a baseclass, to a "GameObject". Also, Unity controls instantiation and serialization of scripts so you can't use constructors.

I have a RoadNetwork script that holds a reference to RoadNodes and RoadCurves, both of which locate RoadNetwork via a singleton and register/deregister themselves. I've put "mini-factories" in RoadNode and RoadCurve that do the hard work of hooking themselves up to a gameobject.

RoadNode first checks with RoadNetwork to make sure there isnt already a node at that same position, by doing this:

```
public static RoadNode2 New(float x, float y, float z)
{
    //First try to find an existing one
    var rn = RoadNetwork.Instance.GetNodeAtPosition(new Vector3(x, y, z))
             ?? UnityReferenceHelper.GetNewGameObjectFor<RoadNode2>(
                 "RoadNode_" + (RoadNetwork.Instance.Nodes.Count + 1).ToString("D3"),
                 RoadNetwork.Instance.transform.FindChild("Nodes"));

    rn.Position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    rn.gameObject.active = true;

    return rn;
}
```

Where the appropriate method in RoadNetwork is:

```
public RoadNode2 GetNodeAtPosition(Vector3 position)
{
    var tempList = new List<RoadNode2>();

    return tempList.Single(x => x.Position == position);
}
```

tempList was an attempt at narrowing down the problem but I get precisely the same error. It should be "Nodes.Single(...", but I doubt it matters. I get the same error if I call the Linq query directly in the New() method.

So yes, this Exception throws and points me to that tempList.Single() line. What would the reason be?

Answer (score 15):

`someEnumerable.Single(...)` throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in `someEnumerable`. Given that you just declared `tempList` to be an empty list, it will always throw an exception.

If you want to retrieve `null` if there are no elements, use `SingleOrDefault`. (This will still throw an exception if the enumerable contains *more* than one element.) If you want the *first* element, so that your enumerable is allowed to contain any number of elements, use `First` (throws an exception if the enumerable contains no elements) or `FirstOrDefault` (returns `null` in the case).

Finally, if you want to simply check if there are any elements of a list matching a given predicate, use `Any`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know some of that, but this isn't the error (i'd get a null ref). It's that the collection for whatever reason is not valid due to its state.

Comment: It's pretty hard to help you if you don't post the exact error. Also, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx the result of using `Single` on an enumerable with not exactly one element is an `InvalidOperationException`, not any kind of null reference exception.

Comment: I just want to say that the "OrDefault" versions worked for my particular situation. I'm also using Unity and I was getting the same InvalidOperation exception. In my case I was using `collection.First()` in LINQ.  Changing that to `.FirstOrDefault` fixed it. The "OrDefault" versions of the LINQ methods are always a safe bet it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Domenic meant to say was that .Single() throws an error whenever more than one element matches your predicate.  Your collection someEnumerable must contain duplicate copies of whatever singleton (not the programming pattern) you're trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a problem with the way you're implementing the singleton pattern in Unity.  If you're getting a null reference exception when checking a list that mean the list hasn't been initialized, so you're probably either not instantiating the singleton or your not accessing the singleton you instantiated.

I usually use a singleton MonoBehaviour attached to a GameObject that instantiates and initializes on first access like this:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/156746/singleton-and-monobehaviour-in-editor.html